# How to install kivy in windows 11

Tags: python-3.x

Installation error

I tried many ways to resolve this but it is not solving
pls help with my problem.
It is showing - 'No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1'

I have a great looking from you.

Comment: Please update to show the things you have tried.